# SvelteKit & Firebase Auth, Two output files share the same path but have different contents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte, vite

I keep getting the error whenever I import `import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";`

> Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules.vite\deps_temp_0b51b981\firebase_auth.js

I've checked all my imports and there are no duplicates, I also checked for capitalization and found no abnormalities. Does anyone else have this issue?

I'll include all my code related to firebase below:

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { collection, doc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";


const firebaseConfig = {
  (deleted)
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const userDoc = (userId) => doc(db, "users", userId);
export {
    auth,
}
```

login.svelte

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    let email, password;
    const dispatcher = createEventDispatcher()
    function login() {
        dispatcher('login', {
            email,
            password
        })
    }
</script>
```

auth/+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import Login from "../../utilities/login.svelte";
    import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
    import { auth, userDoc } from "../../firebase";
    import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
    import { setDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
    export let errors;


    async function signIn(event) {
        try {
            let user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, event.detail.email, event.detail.password)
            await setDoc(userDoc(auth.currentUser.uid), { username: user.user.displayName, email: user.user.email })
            await goto("/admin")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error signing in: ", error)
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: I feel like I should mention none of these are in the same folder.